# I cannot play audio with cordova plugin media

Tags: node.js, cordova, sugarcube

### I want play my audio but I can't

I am encountering an issue with Cordova's Media plugin while attempting to play a sound in my mobile application. Currently, I am using Cordova version 12.0.0, macos 14 sonoma, with cordova plugin media 7.1 and Xcode version 15.

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```js
function playAudio(src) {
    var sv = SugarCube.State.variables;
    if (!musica) {
        if (sv.dispositivo == "ios") {
            musica = new Media("sounds/" + src + ".mp3", null, null, function (status) {
                if (status === Media.MEDIA_STOPPED) musica.play({ playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked: false });
            });
            musica.play({ playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked: false });
            musica.setVolume("" + sv.vmusica);
        } else {
            SugarCube.SimpleAudio.tracks.add("music", "sounds/" + src + ".mp3");
            musica = SugarCube.SimpleAudio.tracks.get("music");
            musica.volume(sv.vmusica);
            musica.play();
            musica.loop(true);
        }
    } else {
        stopAudio();
        playAudio(src);
    }
}
```

I am using Xcode 15 and Cordova 12.0.0, along with Cordova Lib 12.0.1 on macOS 14 Sonoma. Additionally, I'm utilizing Node.js v20 and Cordova Plugin Media version 7.0.

Interestingly, when using macOS 13.3 Ventura, Xcode 14.3, Cordova 11.0.0 with iOS 6.3, and Media Plugin 6.1, the code works correctly.

#### I'm considering three possible solutions:

1. Decode audio to M4A to test if the issue is related to MP3.
2. Attempt a downgrade to Cordova 11.0 and Cordova Plugin Media 6.1 with iOS 6.3.
3. Remove the Media plugin, although I need it for personalized volume controls and fade in/fade out functionalities.

I suspect that the problem may be related to using an older Mac that is not compatible with macOS 14, as it relies on OpenCore. However, even when compiling on an iPhone SE 3rd generation, I still cannot play the sound.

I'm looking for assistance or insights into potential problems with Cordova Media Plugin 7.0 in Xcode 15 with Apache Cordova.

Comment: "but I can't" - What's the error?

Comment: when i execute the error function or succes function  with an alert the succes function was executed. i think that error  is by vitrate audio? is a 128 kbps audio. i think too that eror is caused by e6promise plugin? but i don't know i need test it for more details.

Comment: HEY, I TESTED REMOVING CORDOVA SOCIAL SHARING AND I DON'T HAVE SOUND YET. i need test in a real device, then i will test  with a m4a file to see whats append.

Comment: defenitely ican'tplay audio with cordova 12 and ios .wha canido? how can i get any log for any help?

Answer (score 0):

The Cordova Media Plugin v7 changed the way it parses filepaths and names. If you want to access files inside the www folder you now need to add a / at the start of the filepath.

Try

```
new Media("/sounds/" + src + ".mp3",...)
```

If the sounds directory is inside the www folder your mp3 should play back.

Check https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media/pull/362 for details.

Comment: can you test my code in your project, please?

Comment: I can't test your code since it's incomplete. The lines that you use to play back audio look correct to me. The only difference to my currently working code is that you don't have a slash (/) at the start of your file path.

Comment: here is my new code:

function playAudio(src) {
    musica = new Media("/sounds/"+src+".mp3", null, null, function (status) { if (status === Media.MEDIA_STOPPED) musica.play({playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked: false});});
    musica.play({playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked: false});
    musica.setVolume("1.0");
}

i can't listen audio. but do you think that is for the aditional params?